# Linux - How to replace the last few characters of a file name with a string

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have a list of files and each file-name ends with `(+1)` and I want to replace that `(+1)``of the filename with the date

e.g.: `ABC.DEF(+1)`

Looking for a simple solution which replaces the file-name as below:

`ABC.DEF.20200127`

Answer (score 0):

Use variable substitution. To be honest, I am used to Bash, but according to [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), this also works in ksh:

```
filename="ABC.DEF(+1)"
newfilename="${filename%(+1)}".$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

`"${filename%(+1)}"` strips the string *(1)* from the old filename. The `date` command is used with a format that prints year, month and day of month. This assumes that you want the current date.